# Draw Animated Polyline on Google Maps V2 on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

How to draw a polyline on Google Maps as the below dummy figure:

### ->      ->      ->      ->

The point is that I need the line to have small arrows which animates towards right and then disappear.

Any Idea on how to apply the above behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation

Answer (score 3):

please check [this](http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3)
it will help you.. download [githu](https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock)b code for more clarification.
if its help than vote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a quick poc in animating a drawn route on google map. It uses the android object animator and a custom evaluator for latlng to ease the drawing to make it look like moving.

For animating polyline [routes](http://github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation).

[image]